# sizeof character and strlen string mismatch

Tags: c, char, sizeof, strlen

As per my code, I assume each greek character is stored in 2bytes. 
`sizeof` returns the size of each character as **4** (i.e the sizeof `int`)

How does `strlen` return **16** ? [Making me think each character occupies 2 bytes] (Shouldn't it be 4*8 = 32 ? Since it counts the number of bytes.)

Also, how does `printf("%c",bigString[i]);` print each character properly? Shouldn't it read 1 byte (a char) and then display because of `%c`, why is the greek character not split in this case.

```
strcpy(bigString,"ειδικούς");//greek
sLen = strlen(bigString);
printf("Size is %d\n ",sizeof('ε')); //printing for each character similarly
printf("%s is of length %d\n",bigString,sLen);
int k1 = 0 ,k2 = sLen - 2;

for(i=0;i<sLen;i++)
printf("%c",bigString[i]);
```

Output:

```
Size is 4
 ειδικούς is of length 16
ειδικούς
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Character literals in C have type `int`, so `sizeof('ε')` is the same as `sizeof(int)`.  You're playing with fire in this statement, a bit.  `'ε'` will be a *multicharacter literal*, which isn't standard, and might come back to bite you.  Be careful with using extensions like this one.  Clang, for example, won't accept this program with that literal in it.  GCC gives a warning, but will still compile it.
2. `strlen` returns 16, since that's the number of bytes in your string before the null-terminator.  Your greek characters are all 16 bits long in UTF-8, so your string looks something like:

   ```
   c0c0 c1c1 c2c2 c3c3 c4c4 c5c5 c6c6 c7c7 0
   ```

   in memory, where `c0c0`, for example, is the two bytes of the first character.  There is a *single* null-termination byte in your string.
3. The `printf` appears to work because your terminal is UTF-8 aware.  You *are* printing each byte separately, but the terminal is interpreting the first two prints as a single character, and so on.  If you change that `printf` call to:

   ```
   printf("%d: %02x\n", i, (unsigned char)bigString[i]);
   ```

   You'll see the byte-by-byte behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: But why does `strlen` give `16`? There are 8 characters of type `int` shouldnt that give 4*8 = 32?

Comment: No.  A character literal is an `int`.  The characters in the string are whatever size they need to be - in your case that looks like two bytes apiece.

Comment: btw, sizeof('ε') in visual studio prints 1...and either way this 'ε' is not a string literal but a char literal.

Comment: @Dory, you're probably using a C++ compiler, then.  Who said anything about string literals?

Comment: @CarlNorum Thanks. I am still confused how `printf("%c",bigString[i]);` works fine. I mean shouldn't it display character with UTF-8 `c0` for `bigString[0]`,since I am accessing byte by byte.[How does it use `c0c0` , pick up two bytes and display the correct character]. My single character is not just one character right? (Even gcc warns of multicharacter character)

Comment: I updated my answer to explain that, but the short explanation is that it *doesn't* pick up two bytes.  Your terminal is recombining them for display.

Comment: I don't think `'ε'` is *necessarily* a multi-character literal, which is normally something like `'xy'` (which has an implementation-defined value). I didn't get a warning to that effect when I tried it in a small program. Probably the `ε` character is being represented in UTF-8 as a sequence of 2 bytes, and gcc is treating it as two characters rather than as a UTF-8 sequence. There's probably a range of permissible behaviors depending on locale and so forth. In any case, using `'ε'` in C source is not portable.

Comment: That could be.  I have only a very old gcc here, and clang wouldn't take it at all.  The gcc warning definitely mentioned multicharacter literal, though.  What did you have in your test program?